# ld: library not found for -lgmpxx

Tags: linker, g++, clang, gmp

I'm new to c++ and trying to run the code here https://github.com/chussong/virasoro. After installing GMP and do a "make", I got the following error. I've no idea how to fix it now. Could anybody tell me what should I look into? Is that anything wrong with my gcc? Or how can I reinstall everything on my Mac to fix any possible issues? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: How did you "install GMP"? GMPXX is an optional part of GMP, which may be packaged separately or need some option somewhere so it gets installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, a likely cause of the error above is that you have not installed `libgmpxx`, which is a supplementary library used by GMP to provide C++ class wrappers around the basic GMP library.  If you built GMP from the source provided by the developers of the library (https://gmplib.org/) you can do this by specifying the `--enable-cxx` option when running `configure`.  If you installed a packaged version from some repository, you should look at that repository to see if `libgmpxx` is also available there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Actually, I've downloaded https://gmplib.org/ and  done the ./configure --enable-cxx. Do you have other ideas what went wrong?

Comment: g++ is not finding the library.  You may be able to fix this by adding a -L<directory> option to the LDFLAGS line in the makefile you used to build virasoro, where <directory> is the directory containing the libgmpxx library files.  (When you build gmp by typing "make", it places the libraries in the .libs subdirectory of the build directory.)  For the rest of the compile, you may also need to add -I<directory> options, where <directory> is now the directory containing the .h files for gmp (this could be the build directory for gmp.)

Comment: I had the same problem. The libs were built and installed in /usr/local/lib/ but the linker seems to search only in (/usr)/lib . I wonder what's the recommended option: move them to /usr/lib (where I have an old libgmp but no libgmpxx) , make a symlink there to the files in /usr/local/lib, add /usr/loc/lib to the linker's PATH (gmp is the only thing there), change the PATH for the install (should this be recommended to others [depending on the system/config], before the build)...?